# Search function in ajax not working due to failing where statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a table with sort, page and search function.
First of all, the code runs well, but after I added `where` in my sql, the search function doesn't work anymore.

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php");
 session_start();

$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();

$params = $_REQUEST;

$action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';
$empCls = new cusinfo($connString);

switch($action) 
{
 default:
 $empCls->getEmployees($params);
 return;
}

class cusinfo 
{
protected $conn;
protected $data = array();
function __construct($connString) 
{
    $this->conn = $connString;
}

public function getEmployees($params) 
{
    $this->data = $this->getRecords($params);
    echo json_encode($this->data);
}



function getRecords($params) {

    $rp = isset($params['rowCount']) ? $params['rowCount'] : 10;

    if (isset($params['current'])) { $page  = $params['current']; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $rp;

    $sql = $sqlRec = $sqlTot = $where = '';

    if( !empty($params['searchPhrase']) ) 
    {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" ( NO_ID LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";    
        $where .=" OR TICKET_ID LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR CAT_C_B LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR ORDER_TYPE LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR AGENT_STAFF_NAME LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR EFORM_ID LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR LATEST_ORDER_STATUS LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";
   }
   if( !empty($params['sort']) ) 
    {  
        $where .=" ORDER By ".key($params['sort']) .' '.current($params['sort'])." ";
    }
   // getting total number records without any search
    $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    $uid = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];
    $tid = $_SESSION['tmid'];
    $mid = $_SESSION['mid'];
    $sid = $_SESSION['sid'];

    if($role=="admin")
{           
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cusinfo` where AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID IN (SELECT id FROM `users` where tm_groupid = '$tid') ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;
}
else
{
    .
    .
    .
}

    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') 
    {
        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }
    if ($rp!=-1)
    $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;

    $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot customer data");
    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch customer data");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) 
    { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "current"       => $page, 
        "rowCount"      => 10,          
        "total"         => intval($qtot->num_rows),
        "rows"          => $data   // total data array
        );

    return $json_data;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or problem statement. What behaviour are you experiencing? An error message? Incorrect results? Unexpected behaviour in the code? Please be specific, otherwise it's very difficult to offer meaningful help.

Comment: P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. See what happened to poor Bobby Tables. http://bobby-tables.com/ Please learn to use parameterised queries. This will also, incidentally, reduce the risk of syntax errors arising from chaining strings together to build queries. Currently, depending what is in `searchPhrase`, the query syntax is brittle - a simple apostrophe inside that string could make the query fail to compile.

Comment: Try printing your full query, copy and paste it into phpMyAdmin and check if some error is occuring.

Comment: sorry for late reply,I dint face any error.Is only the search function not working,but dint get any error massage.

Comment: when I type in any word in search box,all the information will show nothing.If normally,it will show the information what I type in to the search box

Comment: Thankyou,problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for all of the reply,this question have been solve by myself.
It can be solve by just change the `where` to `AND` on the code bellow:

```
 if( !empty($params['searchPhrase']) ) 
{   
    $where .=" WHERE";//change this line to $where .=" AND";
.
.
.
}
```